# An invulnerable cyborg and his preteen girlfriend

Tags: story-identification, comics

I'm looking for an indie sci fi comic from the 80's. I believe the comic was Italian originally but was also distributed in the United States. It was about an invulnerable cyborg and his preteen girlfriend. It was censored for being extremely violent and sexual in nature. The art in the comic was amazing, all done with felt tip markers.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like [Rank Xerox/Frigidaire[Ranxerox]](http://paulgravett.com/index.php/articles/article/diabolik_the_fumetti_neri_tradition)(also, the Wikipedia article [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RanXerox)).

> In 1980, the illustrator Tanino Liberatore (above) brought a stunning hyperrealism to Tamburini’s Rank Xerox and the chaotic circus of his near-future Rome, when Tamburini brought the series to the colour pages of the new cool magazine, Frigidaire. Out-of-control, the overmuscled, pig-nosed mechanical brute became the sextoy of Lubna, a precocious Lolita, and in one notorious scene, crushed the hand of an irritating girl pestering him to buy her flowers.

Here's a couple of images as the colour-inked Ranxerox:
[image]
[image]

And before Rank Xerox was carried-over to *Frigidaire*.
[image]

Comment: The first link died, and the little girl was quite polite about her flowers.